# Is there a way to simplify this C++ integer loop array?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, integer

This is an array that I've been learning to make in C++. Is there any way that I would be able to simplify this further?

---

cout << "Array of integer values" << endl;
        cout << "=======================" << endl;

```
    int value[5] = { 17, 34, 51, 68, 85 }; // Creates an integer array list that contain a series of 5 values

    for (int loop = 0; loop < 5; loop++) {
        cout << "Integer value " << loop << ": " << value[loop] << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "Array of double values" << endl; // First endl creates a blank line
    cout << "=======================" << endl;

    double numbers[10] = { 12.1, 24.2, 36.3, 48.4, 60.5, 72.6, 84.7, 96.8, 212.9, 3.0 }; // Creates an double integer array list that contains a series of 10 values

    for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) { // Loops array
        // Adding example " numbers[loop] = 77; " would set every number to 77

        cout << "Element at index " << loop << ": " << numbers[loop] << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "Initializing with zero values" << endl; // First endl creates a blank line
    cout << "=======================" << endl;

    for (int loop = 0; loop < 1; loop++) { // Loops array
        // Adding " numbers[loop] = 77; " would set every number to 77
        cout << "Element at index " << loop << ": " << numbers[loop] << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "Initializing with strings" << endl; // First endl creates a blank line
    cout << "=======================" << endl;

    // Array of strings
    string text = ( "Chair", "Table", "Plate" ) ;

    ;       for (int loop = 0; loop < 3; loop++) { // Loops array
        cout << "Element at index " << loop << ": " << text[loop] << endl;

        return 0;
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to do

Comment: you could delete `int numberArray[8] = {};` it serves no purpose. No computation is really being done so what do you mean by simplify?

Comment: A range-based for loop?

Comment: By simplify, I mean how can I condense the code further. I'm just making a basic array of integers. I removed the numberArray.

Comment: You could write a function that prints an array. Is that the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: Uh yeah. How would I add a print function?

Comment: Do you know how to add a function that does nothing? How about a function that prints "hello"? A function that takes an `int` argument? Two arguments? Do you know how to pass an array to a function? Which part is giving you trouble?

Comment: Uh I know that "cout" and "cin" can be used to print text, and that if, else and else-if can take integers. Not sure about passing arrays to functions.

Answer (score 1):

You never use your array declared here:

```
int numberArray[8] = {};
```

and this whole part looks like a repeat from above:

> ```
> for (int loop = 0; loop < 10; loop++) { // Loops array
> // Adding " numbers[loop] = 77; " would set every number to 77
> cout << "Element at index " << loop << ": " << numbers[loop] << endl;
> ```

As far as "simplifying" this, if you are using arrays of the same data type, you can write a function that accepts the array, the number of elements, and loops through the array outputting whatever you desire. Then you can just call this function from your `main` function each time instead of repeating the `for` loops

Comment: I changed the code, where I added a string array. However, it is not displaying the text array at the end. Any ideas? I modified the OP to show the code.

Comment: `string text = ( "Chair", "Table", "Plate" ) ;` is not a valid array initialization (or string initialization for that matter!). What you may have been trying for was `string text[] = {"Chair", "Table", "Plate"};` This should fix your code (and you are also missing a close brace `}` to close your last for loop).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void Printer (const vector<T> &t_elementsToPrint)
{

    // For simple value printing
    for (auto value : t_elementsToPrint)
        cout << value << "\n";

    // If you want to know the index number
    for (auto it = begin(t_elementsToPrint); it != end(t_elementsToPrint); ++it)
    {
        cout << "Element at index " << distance(begin(t_elementsToPrint), it) << " : " << *it << "\n";
    }
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

    vector<double> numbers = { 12.1, 24.2, 36.3, 48.4, 60.5, 72.6, 84.7, 96.8, 212.9, 3.0 }; // Creates an double integer array list that contains a series of 10 values

    Printer<double>(numbers);

    vector<int> numbers2 = { 17, 34, 51, 68, 85 };

    Printer<int>(numbers2);

    return 0;
}
```

You could change the container from vector to array or other that might fit you, unless you really need raw access, I would recommend sticking with STL Containers if what you are looking for is simplicity.